# Ajax returnText has 2 empty indexes

Tags: javascript, ajax

Whenever i make an ajax call i always get a string with 2 empty index numbers. Why is that and is there anyway to fix it? Should I just live with it and use index + 2 whenever i want to fetch a char from it? Am I the stupid one who is doing something extremly wrong?

I have not inserted a real ajax function since it won't work on this site and my own that I use is very messy.

```js
function ajax(callback){
  
  /* Does it ajax stuff here in pure js*/
  
 
  /**/
  
  
  }






/* Our ajax request */
ajax(function(responseText){ 

// This is where we do something with the string we got form the ajax
  
// Let's say that the ajax returned a document with the text: sample text
  
  
  
  // This will print out the whole string and it works perfectly
  console.log(responseText); 

  
  // This SHOULD print out the first letter/char which is "s"
  // But it dosn't by some reason!!
  console.log(responseText[0]);
  
  
  // But this does print out the first letter which is "s" by some reason
 console.log(responseText[2]);
  
  
  // So this means that there must be 2 undefined/empty indexes of the returned string.
  
  

});
```

Comment: Reduce your admittedly messy code to a simple version that reproduces the issue and share that here. Also show us the actual response from the server, and pertinent code that generates it.

Comment: @JAAulde Thanks I will do that in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have extra whitespace in the response.

Use [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove it. Or better yet always use json for tasks like this

Try

```
ajax(function(responseText) {
  // clean outside whitespce
  responseText = responseText.trim();


  console.log(responseText);    

  console.log('First char=',responseText[0]);    

  console.log('Third char=',responseText[2]); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some whitespace in your response which is returned from ajax() function. Try to use the trim() method as shown as following:

```
responseText = responseText.trim();
```